# Using Linkedin Access Token

Tags: linkedin-api, access-token, api-key

I've successfully gotten my access token to the LinkedIn api! However, I can only seem to make this request call:

```
 GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me/
```

When I try to look up another public member's information using:

```
 GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:{person ID})
```

I get the 403 error saying: serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET- vanityName /people","status":403.

This happens when I try to look up the member using the vanity name as well. Can someone explain why this is happening even though I've gotten the access token?

Answer (score 0):

It's what the error message says: LinkedIn hasn't given your application permission to fetch other people's profiles. You can only fetch your own. Those APIs exist, but aren't given to everyone.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Do you happen to know how those API's are accessed? Or how one might begin applying for access?

Comment: They're essentially not available.